# Get all elements that are not in multiple lists

Tags: java, list

i have multiple (three or more) lists like:

```
[a, b, c, d, a];
[b, d, e, c, a];
[c, f, a];
```

Now i want all elements, which are either in a single list or in multiple lists, but not in all lists!
The result for the example above should be:

```
[b, d, e, f];
```

Any solutions?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem with the code you have so far?

Comment: ill give you hint, `removeAll`

Comment: Can the same element appear multiple times in the same list?  In any event, you probably want a `Map` that maps each element to the number of lists you find it in.

Comment: If you can't have dups, I would suggest looking at `Set`, which guarantees uniqueness.  Also, what @user902383, `removeAll()` would be a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the [retainAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method to find entries in all lists. The rest is just simple collections stuff.

Once you have your list of items in all lists, use a `Set` (to ensure you throw away duplicates) to gather all elements in all lists and then use `removeAll` using your list of entries that appear in all lists.

```
public void test() {
  List<String> aList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "a"));
  List<String> bList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("b", "d", "e", "c", "a"));
  List<String> cList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("c", "f", "a"));
  // Not in all lists.
  List<String> inAll = new ArrayList<>(aList);
  inAll.retainAll(bList);
  inAll.retainAll(cList);
  // Unique results - all items in all lists.
  Set<String> result = new HashSet<>(aList);
  result.addAll(bList);
  result.addAll(cList);
  // But nothing that is in all lists.
  result.removeAll(inAll);
  System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.util.List`, if you have arrays use `Arrays.asList( arr );` and then `list.contains( el );` to check whether some of the lists contains the current element ...